# Defining Python Classes

Tags: python

I am a beginner with Python as I have probably stated in my previous questions, and some of the topics that I have been comming across are not given the in depth explanations that I would require to underswtand the material so I have a question. The question that is beign asked is " Add method distance() to the class Point. It takes another Point object as input and returns the distance to that point (from the point invoking the method).

What it is looking for is the following result when this is all input into the module

```
>>> c = Point()
>>> c.setx(0)
>>> c.sety(1)
>>> d = Point()
>>> d.setx(1)
>>> d.sety(0)
>>> c.distance(d)
1.4142135623730951
```

Here is what I have:

```
class Point:
    def setx(self, xcoord):
        self.x = xcoord
    def sety(self, ycoord):
        self.y = ycoord
    def get(self):
        return(self.x, self.y)
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
```

And then I am not sure if I would need to define distance in what way. Thank you.

I have a clear baseline of how I am pretty sure I would begin this, but then when it comes to defining distance, I am very much stuck.

Comment: Please don't use getters and setters in Python. Just access the instance variable directly, or use [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for non-trivial instance variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a method like this

```
def distance(self, other):
    dist = math.hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
    return dist
```

You also need to `import math` at the start of your program

Aside: It's not pythonic at all to have your `setx` and `sety` methods. You should just assign to the attributes directly. eg `c.x = 0`

```
Help on built-in function hypot in module math:

hypot(...)
    hypot(x, y)

    Return the Euclidean distance, sqrt(x*x + y*y).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without set and get.  `__init__` is optional.  I added `__call__` instead of `get`.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, *terms):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def __call__(self):
        return(self.x, self.y)
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy
    def distance(self, other):
        dist = math.hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
        return dist

>>> c = Point()
>>> c.x = 0
>>> c.y = 1
>>> d = Point()
>>> d.x = 1
>>> d.y = 0
>>> c()
(1, 0)
>>> c.distance(d)
1.4142135623730951
```